# building a photo uploader using the jquery-file-upload plugin and custom ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm building a photo upload form and have decided to use the jQuery plugin `jquery-file-upload` but have come across some issues... and questions.

First, the code I'm using (going with the `basic` version):

```
// File upload function
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('#pick-photos').click(function(){

        jQuery('#file-upload').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    jQuery('#photo-upload').fileupload({

        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {

            jQuery.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            jQuery('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });

            // Append the file name and file size
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                         .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

            jQuery('#upload').click(function() {

                data.submit();
            });         
        },

        progressall: function(e, data) {

            // Calculated the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            jQuery('#upload-progress .progress-bar').css(

                'width',
                progress + '%'
           );
        },

    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {

        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {

            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {

            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {

        return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }

});
```

The issue I'm facing is an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'` on this line of code `jQuery('#photo-upload').fileupload({`

Secondly, I'm wondering how to include custom ajax in this code... so that I can change the page content based on success or error.

Any help is greatfully accepted!

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute some code on success or on error (or both), the [jquery-file-upload](/questions/tagged/jquery-file-upload) provides some callback :

- [done](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#done) (equivalent of success)
- fail (equivalent of error)
- always (equivalent of complete)

Each of these callbacks have same parameters than the add callback's one.

The basic version wiki gives an example :

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo(document.body);
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

---

For your issue do you include these files?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, so I made sure that I had all the files listed connected like I should; but I'm still receiving the error. I had another error as well that I hadn't mentioned, but which might actually be the main issue... `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'widget'` on line 62 of jquery.fileupload.js which reads `$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {` NOTE: no I have not messed around in that file.

Comment: I'm using wordpress and am using the version of jquery they already have which happens to be 1.10.2 could this be the reason?

Comment: Your JQuery version should be OK. I've make some tests here : http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/MEA58/3/ but I had to invent the HTML. I think you can't call `data.response` into the `add` callback. And I don't understand what is the `tpl` object.

Comment: Umm... I just tested the jsfiddle which works pretty much the way I want... however, when I copy and pasted it still gives me the same errors! I've got no clue where or what to do now.

Comment: Are you sure that all required .js files are well downloaded? (f12/network tab on Chrome). If so do you use other JS library? Is your website online?

Comment: Link: http://demo.designer17.com/dominion-skills/event-photo-uploader/
Inspect Element to see the errors... as you won't even be able to se the login form to go any further. :(

Comment: Can you try to link the widget.js file before the iframe-transport one ?

Comment: Okay, talked to a friend of mine and discovered that my js files were being called in the wrong order. It is now running! Now to make it work the way I need it to. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: So, I have everything working nicely but I'm still needing to add error handling and have a question ... if my return is in the format of `JSON` will the `fail` function work or will it read any `JSON` response as a success message?

Comment: I think that if your HTTP response header contains a successfull code, the fail function will never be called. Did you read [this part of thé documentation?](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#fail)

Comment: Yes, I have read that part of the documentation; what that is saying is no matter what response is given by `JSON` (whether success or error) it will not trigger the `fail` function. I'm pretty sure the `fail` function is only called for `JS` errors. Hence the reason for my question. ;)

Comment: I've make the test on my own with one of my script: I succeed in calling the fail function just by making my server returning a 404 code status (and the JSON data is still well passed). @Designer17

Comment: Could you share that in a pastebin or jsfiddle etc.? It would be really helpful! ;)

Comment: @Designer17 : I use [tag:Laravel] framework so I just have to add the status code in this function: `return Response::json($my_Json_Data, 404);`. Your server framework should provide the same functionality. In the end I think it's the `http_response_code` PHP's function which is used. If you really want my code in pastebin, tell me it.